# select query to get first row from rows having multiple id's.(without partition by)

Tags: sql-server, mysql-workbench

```
id   date         amount      documentNo     paperID
1    2015/10/15   500         1234             34
1    2015/10/15   100         1332             33
2    2015/10/13   200         1302             21
2    2015/10/13   400         1332             33
3    2015/11/23   500         1332             43
```

I should get the output as:

```
id        date      amount       documentNo     paperID
1       2015/10/15   500         1234             34
2       2015/10/13   200         1302             21
3       2015/11/23   500         1332             43
```

Please suggest a simple select query to fetch only one row without partition by. Note: the date remain same for a particular id.

Comment: 3 questions: 1) What have you tried so far? 2) Why are you imposing a restriction on using window functions 3) What do you consider the 1st row (because database rows are unordered unless you specify a specific order based on column values)?

Comment: 1) i am not able to figure out a way. 2) window functions do not function on my server 3) if I can get any one of the row with same id, i am fine with it.

Comment: what is your database server?  You have sql server tagged, that should be able to handle window functions just fine

Comment: Can you provide a partition by query in sql server 2014?

Comment: of course you can. Did you try it?  If it doesn't work, that would make for an interesting question.

Comment: are you using `SQL Server` or `MySQL` ? you have both tagged

Answer (score 2):

Try a null-self-join. Basically you are comparing each row to some other version of that row ,but, via an inequality (here I have used documentNo) you end-up with a single row that has no match.

See this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d955a/1)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`id` int, `date` datetime, `amount` int, `documentNo` int, `paperID` int)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`id`, `date`, `amount`, `documentNo`, `paperID`)
VALUES
    (1, '2015-10-15 00:00:00', 500, 1234, 34),
    (1, '2015-10-15 00:00:00', 100, 1332, 33),
    (2, '2015-10-13 00:00:00', 200, 1302, 21),
    (2, '2015-10-13 00:00:00', 400, 1332, 33),
    (3, '2015-11-23 00:00:00', 500, 1332, 43)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT
      t1.*
FROM table1 AS t1
      LEFT OUTER JOIN table1 AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
                  AND t1.date = t2.date
                  AND t2.documentNo < t1.documentNo
WHERE t2.ID IS NULL
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d955a/1/0)**:

```
| id |                       date | amount | documentNo | paperID |
|----|----------------------------|--------|------------|---------|
|  1 |  October, 15 2015 00:00:00 |    500 |       1234 |      34 |
|  2 |  October, 13 2015 00:00:00 |    200 |       1302 |      21 |
|  3 | November, 23 2015 00:00:00 |    500 |       1332 |      43 |
```

EDIT: There are several approaches to this problem even without windowing functions such as row_number() , here is a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895110/row-number-in-mysql) covering some MySQL specific alternatives.

Comment: Added link to previous question.